# Lazy django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader

Tags: django, django-templates

I get this when trying to access an existing template:

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/blah-blah/venv3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/polymer.html (File does not exist)
/blah-blah/venv3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/polymer.html (File does not exist)
```

This is a brand new project and, for lack of a better place, I have place my templates in the top dir:

```
├── manage.py
├── polymertest
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── static
│   ├── bower_components
│   └── polymer
└── templates
    └── polymer.html
```

I am able to solve the problem by adding `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` to `settings.TEMPLATES['DIRS']`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

This does look suspicious to me, but according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader), this is expected behavior: you need to configure DIRS. My question is then:

Where should I place my templates in a brand new Django project so that they are found by the `filesystem.Loader` without configuration? Or is this not possible at all?

This seems like a common use case to me: create a project, add a template, add a view and *boom*, serve it! I am surprised that it is not automatically covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a settings file created with `./manage.py startproject`, the `APP_DIRS` option is `True`. That means that when you create an app, any templates in that app's template directory will be found.

The [`DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#the-dirs-option) option defaults to an empty list. That means that apart from app template directories, there are not any template directory that always work without configuration changes.

Setting `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],` is a common approach, and it's [suggested in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#loader-types).

Comment: Ok. I guess that my problem starts because I refuse to create an app for a very simple project, and I just dump all my code into the `proj/proj` directory. I do not know if this is also a common approach, but for me does not make much sense to create a project *and then* add an app, when my project has a single app - that is, my project *is* the app.

Comment: Your app might be more reusable if you created a separate app, but you can use whatever project layout works for you. Setting `DIRS` is a one line change, and if that's too much, you can create a `template` to use with the [`startproject`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#startproject-projectname-destination) command.